# Change IP address of IP CAM using CMS software

Tags: digital-cameras, surveillance-cameras, ip-address

I'm using IP camera - as an input for my IOT project.
IP cam default IP is `192.168.1.10` and in order to use it in my network I need to change its default IP.

My network address is `192.168.3.x`.  Seller instructions [image: instructions] are clear and reasonable, but my network address is not as his, causing `IP SEARCH` not to find this device.

I know that it is connected as needed since my NVR detects camera, with exact IP, but changing IP cannot be done using NVR GUI...

Any ideas ?

Guy

Comment: I'm not clear what you are actually asking here.

Comment: @hardillb - I tried to write it more clearly. I'll try to explain it again : default ip is `192.168.1.10` and ,y metwork ip range is `192.168.3.x`. the issue is changing its ip address, since it have its ip which is not my network's address range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I found quite quick and usefull- was like that:

1. Connect IPCAM directly to PC's LAN port
2. Change Adapter settings ( via Control Panel ) to `192.168.1.X`
3. logoff
4. Connect using web page with default ip `192.168.1.10` and change to desired IP.

** this youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtFqQ9zpzq0) helped a lot !